# Ajax Json Parse Error in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am getting the following parse error from the Ajax call.
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

```
               $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "QueryOrder",
                        data: dataString,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(
                            data) {;
                            alert("I am in Success");
                            alert(data);

                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR,
                            textStatus,
                            errorThrown) {
                            alert("Error Return from Ajax");
                            alert(jqXHR
                                .getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
                            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                            alert(jqXHR);
                            alert(errorThrown);
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    }); //end of Ajax call
```

I have verified the json object which is getting generated in the servlet code and its valid

{"orderObj":[{"FIRST_NAME":"John","LAST_NAME":"Mkay"}]}

and response.setContentType("application/json"); is used to set the response.

I have used tried the following jQuery lib versions

and getting the same parse eof error.

I have also tried changing the dataType to 'Json', 'text', 'json/text' and even removing the dataType parameter and nothing is working. Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Comment: `success: function(
                            data) {;` That semicolon will throw an error

Comment: What's the server response header saying? Does the response preview show json?

Comment: yeah the response shows the content type as json
***************************
Content-Length 0
Content-Type application/json
Date Tue, 18 Nov 2014 21:36:59 GMT
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1

Comment: Just because it actually happened to me, notice that the dataType is "json" and not "application/json" as the standard mime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved by adding

```
response.getWriter().write(myObj.toString());
```

to the servlet code. Thanks all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have to send the data to the server in a proper json serializer:

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
```

Comment: I have tried this but getting the same error. the issue is with the Json data which Ajax is receiving. Somehow it is not able to parse it even though its valid json Object

Comment: I see. You can check if you json is valid here: http://jsonlint.com/ and if it is valid, maybe try another browser or cleaning the cache.

Comment: I did verify the json using jsonlint.com and it is a valid one. Is there a specific jQuery.js lib version which we need to use while for json related ajax call? I have tried 1.7.2/jquery.js and also jquery-1.10.2.js and both are giving json parse error

Comment: Are you familiar with the method getJSON()? You could try that approach and see if the problem persists:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: I have tried getJSON() but now the data returned in function(data) is null. I can see that the JSONObject formed in the servlet is valid but not returned to getJSON()

Comment: If it's happening with both $.getJSON() and $.ajax I would say something is coming up in your target page that is breaking the parsing. It would help if you could add to your question the code in your QueryOrder page (removing all compromising or sensitive information of course).

Answer (score 0):

Posting the entire code. Ajax call is returning null JSON object

**************HTML****************************************

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: .6em 0;
}

div#orders-contain {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

div#orders-contain table {
    margin: 1em 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 150%;
}

div#orders-contain table td, div#orders-contain table th {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: .6em 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#query-order").click(function(e) {
            dataString = "countryCode=";
            alert("on Load");
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "QueryOrder",
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(
                        data) {
                        alert("I am in Success");
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR,
                        textStatus,
                        errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error Return from Ajax");
                        alert(jqXHR
                            .getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
                        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                        alert(jqXHR);
                        alert(errorThrown);
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                }); //end of Ajax call
        }); // end of click function
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="orders-contain" class="ui-widget">
        <h1>Orders:</h1>
        <table id="Orders" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Customer Number</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Date of Order</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Order Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button id="query-order">Query Orders</button>
</body>
</html>
```

*****************************Servlet code************************

```
package com.order.pkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class QueryOrder extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public QueryOrder() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           doPost(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */ 
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");        

        response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400"); 
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded");

            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            String user = "dbtest";
            String pwd = "dbtest";
            Connection DB_mobile_conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,
                    pwd);
            System.out.println("Database Connect ok");

            String query = "select * from ORDER_HEADERS";

            ArrayList<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();


            if (query != null) {
                Statement query_stmt = DB_mobile_conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet query_rs = query_stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (query_rs.next()) {
                    Order orderobj = new Order();
                    orderobj.setFIRST_NAME(query_rs.getString("FIRST_NAME").trim());
                    orderobj.setLAST_NAME(query_rs.getString("LAST_NAME").trim());
                    orderList.add(orderobj);
                }
                query_rs.close();
                query_stmt.close();
            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
            JsonElement orderObj = gson.toJsonTree(orderList);
            myObj.add("orderObj", orderObj);
            System.out.println(myObj);      

            System.out.println(response.getContentType());              

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println("Exception = " + exp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use out.println(myObj) instead of system.out.println(myObj) as sop prints to console and your ajax call is coming back with no response!

I'm not sure if " System.out.println(response.getContentType();" is useful ..
Try commenting it!!